# Analog of the Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Lets consider two random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$, which satisfy such conditions:

$$E\xi = E\eta = 0,~~~ D\xi = D\eta = 1;$$
$$\operatorname{cov}(\xi, \eta) = \rho.$$

How can we prove?

$$E\bigl( \max\{\xi^2,\eta^2\}\bigr) \le 1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}$$

Comment: What is $D$ here?

Comment: @ClementC. It was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your D is an expectation here.

Here are the key steps:

1) $\max(a,b) = \frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$

2) $|c^2-d^2| = |c+d||c-d|$

3) Cauchy Schwarz gives $E|UV| \leq \sqrt{E[U^2]}\sqrt{E[V^2]}$

This is a sketch. Just substitute appropriately to get your answer.

Comment: thank you, that has helped